# How to put annotation in rest-auth user

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to add some annotation in authenticated User using rest-auth
Here is my code in `serializers.py`

```
  class CustomUserSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
        test = serializers.IntegerField()
        class Meta:
            model=User
            fields='__all__'
```

And here is my code in `views.py`

```
class CustomUserView(UserDetailsView):
    queryset= User.objects.annotate(test=Sum('logs__work_hours'))
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
```

but I am having this error after running the system

**

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `test` on
> serializer `CustomUserSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
> incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'test'.

**

Answer (score 0):

In this context, `queryset` is ignored.

Why? In your program, you're subclassing `UserDetailsView` from `django-rest-auth`. That implements `get_object()` like so:

```
    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

With no reference to the queryset variable.

You need to override `get_object()` in `CustomUserView`, copying the above implementation, and setting a test attribute on the user.

```
    def get_object(self):
        user = self.request.user
        user.test = ...  # put query to get value of test here
        return user
```